# Incorrect SQL statement using FOR ALL ENTRIES and NOT EXISTS

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I am trying to do a selection of the table `VBRK`, with the goal that it will select all of the data from `VBRK`, without those data where the column `NETWR` is 0. The code is as below:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM vbrk INTO TABLE gt_vbrk
      FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_vbfa_inv
      WHERE vbeln = gt_vbfa_inv-vbeln
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM vbrk 
                        INTO TABLE gt_vbrk
                        FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_vbfa_inv
                        WHERE netwr = 0). //Here I get an error
```

So I am getting an error that it is not grammatically correct to do the `NOT EXISTS`. Can someone tell me how can I fix the upper code or do a selection where the data with `NETWR = 0` will not be selected?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add netwr to the WHERE condition, NE is for not equal:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * 
        FROM vbrk 
        INTO TABLE gt_vbrk
        FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_vbfa_inv
        WHERE vbeln EQ gt_vbfa_inv-vbeln
          AND netwr NE 0.
```

Answer (score 2):

For your information, there are few misconceptions in your original SQL query:

1. Concerning `FOR ALL ENTRIES`, it can be used only in the main SELECT, you can't use in a nested SELECT (as you do).
2. You are also not authorized to use `INTO` in a nested SELECT, it must be used only inside the main SELECT.
3. When you use `EXISTS`, you must indicate a kind of join information between the main query and the SELECT after EXISTS. If you need to do it with the same table, a table alias is to be assigned so that you can indicate the origin of the columns.
4. Within SAP ERP software/ABAP-based systems, all database tables have a primary key, so it's not needed to use DISTINCT if you get all the columns of the primary key (as you do). NB: the primary key of `VBRK` is made of the columns `MANDT` and `VBELN` (the first one is usually never needed in ABAP).
5. It is usually bad practice to select all the columns from a table (`SELECT * FROM ...`), you should indicate only the columns you really need.
6. Don't forget the spaces everywhere in ABAP, they are required.

József answer is correct. Just for your information, the following SQL statement gives the same result, it shows the difference with what you could have done:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_vbfa_inv,
         vbeln TYPE vbrk-vbeln,
       END OF ty_vbfa_inv.
DATA: gt_vbrk     TYPE TABLE OF vbrk,
      gt_vbfa_inv TYPE TABLE OF ty_vbfa_inv..

SELECT * FROM vbrk INTO TABLE gt_vbrk
     FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_vbfa_inv
     WHERE vbeln = gt_vbfa_inv-vbeln
       AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM vbrk              "<====== space needed
                        AS vbrk2                        "<====== needed alias
*                       INTO TABLE gt_vbrk              "<====== forbidden
*                       FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_vbfa_inv  "<====== forbidden
                       WHERE netwr = 0
                         AND vbrk2~vbeln = vbrk~vbeln )."<====== join needed
```